# How many SCL and SDA pins does PIC18F26K83 support?

Tags: pic, i2c

I will use PIC18F26K83 as a master and I will have 4 different slaves that will be communicating with my master. In the datasheet for pps mapping only I2C1 Data input and I2C2 Data input pins are given as default. So I started to think    that, this MCUonly support 2 different I2C communication (probably I'm wrong). Is there a limit for this MCU such as how many SDA and SCL pins can I assign? Can I have 4 different slaves which means can I have 4 in and 4 output pins?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The PIC18F26K83 support only one I2C, as written in datasheet.
With PPS (Peripheral Pin Select) registers I2C1SCLPPS and I2C1SDAPPS you can select any I/O pin of MCPu. By default is Pin14 defined as SCL1 and Pin15 as SDA1.

If you want to communicate with 4 I2C slaves than any slave need EN (enable) pin. With this EN pin you should select the slave at communication time. Normally is single I2C master able to communicate with up to 10 slaves.

Comment: Or instead of enable pin would a multiplexer work? Would it prevent address conflict of same addressed 3 batteries?

Comment: If you mean PPS multiplexer then yes it is possible! You can set via PPS for any slave own SCL pin.

Comment: I mean some kind of multiplexer like this [http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tca9546a.pdf] it says SMBus switch

Comment: Ahh, you can use MCPu PPS.

Comment: But in that case I need to use enable pins for 3 of my slaves because 3 of them have same address :(

Comment: No! In that case you need to use 3 pins for SCL (one per slave) and one common for SDA! EN pin on slaves can be always enabled!

Answer (score 0):

There are 4 pins which means 2 for SDA and 2 for SCL. Your best bet to use multiplexer.